# Captcha plugin for Agiletoolkit

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, atk4, agiletoolkit

Is there any addon which adds captcha to Form_Field?

Like

```
$f = $this->add('Form');
$f->addField('Line','captcha')->addCaptcha();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two

Captcha based on Imagick
https://github.com/rvadym/x_captcha

reCaptha from Google 
https://github.com/rvadym/x_recaptcha

Comment: Vadim, you should really write some read-me instructions asap!!